# How to configure tomcat so I can run my (java) web app at localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

I've made a very small web app with eclipse, including

- HomeServlet.java
- home.jsp
- web.xml

just echo'ing Hello world!. I've made my own build.xml file, and it's building succesfull.
So now I've got my build folder, where HomeServer.class is located, and my web folder, where home.jsp is located.

I've downloaded Tomcat 7 (and got it working at localhost:8080), how can I configure my server.xml in a way that I can view my app at something like: localhost/app/home ? I'm running Windows

Comment: You need to build WAR/EAR file and deploy it on your tomcat

Comment: http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/ and http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/setup-servlet-development-environment.html

Comment: you dont need to build a war for this 3 files, just put them in webapps folder in correct hierarchy as mentioned below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to configure anything in Tomcat. You should just create a directory structure like the following, and drop this directory in the ***webapps*** folder of Tomcat:

```
myWebApp
    WEB-INF
        classes
            com
                mypackage 
                    HelloServlet.class
        web.xml (optional if the servlet uses annotations)
    home.jsp
```

This is the structure of a standard Java EE webapp. It's described in every tutorial about Java EE webapps, and in [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html).

Note that it's a good idea to rely on Ant, Gradle or Maven to build your app, but that Eclipse (in its enterprise edition) supports Java EE webapps, and can create this structure for you and deploy the app directly from the IDE.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to have tomcat look in my workspace directory for the files? Or should I have my Eclipse build the files inside the Tomcat directory? Also I know that the IDE's have integrated tomcat service, but I want to run tomcat seperately.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have an integrated Tomcat. It allows you to start, stop and deploy to an external Tomcat from the IDE. You just need to tell Eclipse where your Tomcat install is, and which version it has. And what Eclipse does is what you want: it makes Tomcat look for the webapp files in the Eclipse workspace directly.

Comment: Would it be possible to open the tomcat log? The reason I want to run tomcat independently is so I can have a window open with the tomcat log, for debugging purposes

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. Tomcat doesn't care (and doesn't know) if you launch it from the command line, or if you launch it from Eclipse.